# Can changing IMEI of an Android smartphone make WiFi & Bluetooth refuse to work?

Tags: wi-fi, imei

I recently used a third party software to change the IMEI of a device but then WiFi, Bluetooth is not turning on when I try to. The switch turns on and then the system turns it off in an instant. Is there a third party software I can use to tell if the system detects a Bluetooth/WiFi hardware installed on the smartphone and could the IMEI change have made the hardware non-functional?

Comment: Wifi and Bluetooth don't depends on IMEI. Most likely the IMEI changer software has destroyed something and now those services fail to start.

Comment: Is there something I can use to check if the adapter is installed?

Comment: What adapter are you talking about? To make it work again restore the old state by an undo operation the IMEI changer hopefully provides or reinstall the original firmware hoping that it includes the part where the IMEI changes has modified the system.

Comment: What Android device and what third-party software did you try? AFAIK, changing IMEI needs root access, so if the device is not rooted, then it would just fail... unless the software also rooted the device... and doing other things.

Comment: There are 2 questions here. The first is on-topic, and the second would be on-topic at Software Recommendations SE.

Comment: @AndrewT. You are correct the device is rooted.